# Using SharePoint Site Template Powershell - Home Page Layout/Web Parts not working - SharePoint Online - Modern Pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, modern-pages, sharepoint-online-powershell

I am using PowerShell Get-SPOSiteScriptFromWeb and Add-SPOSiteScript etc.  I am able to copy links, create lists, etc.  But my HomePage webparts/layout is not reflected when I apply the site script and design.  I've been looking for solutions for days and I'm getting so tired >_<;

I saw that PNP should be able to do this but my global admin has not given permissions to the new PNP Shell yet in azure.

My desired Layout: [image: desired layout]

New Site Layout/Template - looks just like the default layout after applying the new site design script.  What am I missing? or doing wrong?

Please help. thank you.

Code Sample:

```
#Define Parameters
$AdminCenterURL = "https://wafd-admin.sharepoint.com"
$SiteURL = "https://wafd.sharepoint.com/sites/TemplateTest"
$relativeListUrls = ("/Lists/Issues Log", "Lists/Artifacts Checklist")
  
#Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminCenterURL -credential (Get-Credential)

#Get the site schema & add site schema as site script 
 $extracted = Get-SPOSiteScriptFromWeb `
    -WebUrl $SiteURL `
    -IncludeBranding `
    -IncludeTheme `
    -IncludeRegionalSettings `
    -IncludeSiteExternalSharingCapability `
    -IncludeLinksToExportedItems `
    -IncludedLists ($relativeListUrls)
 
 $SiteScript = Add-SPOSiteScript `
    -Title "Mark template site v4" `
    -Description " Attempt 5 ." `
    -Content $extracted

#Create the site design 
$SiteDesign = Add-SPOSiteDesign -Title "Mark Template Site V5" -WebTemplate 64 -SiteScripts $SiteScript.id

write-host(" Mission Complete Yahoo ?");
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mark Apolinar, I am currently doing some research on this issue, will let you know as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you and appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though what you need to use is a PnP provisioning template, which allows you to define the content and structure of pages as well.

[Introducing the PnP provisioning engine](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/introducing-the-pnp-provisioning-engine)